# Proof verification involving numerically equivalent sets

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

I tried out a proof exercise where the problem was the following:

> Let $S$ be a collection of $n \geq 2$ numerically equivalent sets.   Prove that these sets can be shown to be numerically equivalent by means of $n - 1$ bijective functions between pairs of sets in $S$.

Is the following proof correct? If not, is there anything I can do to improve? Thank you!

**Proof:** Let $S:=\{A_1,A_2,\dots,A_n\}$, where $A_i,A_j:i,j\in\mathbb{N}$ are sets such that $|A_i|=|A_j|$ and $1\leq i,j \leq n$.

We need only show there exists one bijective function $f_i:A_i\to A_{i+1}$ in order to conclude $|A_i|=|A_{i+1}|$. After this, we would want to find another bijective function $f_{i+1}:A_{i+1}\to A_{i+2}$ to show $|A_{i+1}|=|A_{i+2}|$. If we continue in this pattern, the last bijective function to find in that pattern would be $f_{n-1}:A_{n-1}\to A_n$ that would show $|A_{n-1}|=|A_n|$.

Say we start with some bijective function $f_1:A_1 \to A_2$. Then this bijective function would prove $|A_1|=|A_2|$. After this, the next bijective functions $f_2,\dots,f_{n-1}$ would prove $|A_2|=|A_3|,|A_3|=|A_4|,\dots,|A_{n-1}|=|A_n|$, which would imply $|A_2|=|A_3|=|A_4|=\dots=|A_n|$. Using this method, a total of $n-1$ bijections $f_1,\dots,f_{n-1}$ are used to prove $|A_1|=|A_2|=|A_3|=\dots=|A_n|$, meaning all of the sets in $S$ are numerically equivalent. $\blacksquare$

Comment: I'm a bit confused by the exercise. $S$ is defined to be a collection of numerically equivalent sets, and the goal is to show that $S$ contains numerically equivalent sets. It seems to me that this is true as a tautology, and that one does not need any proof.

Comment: However, your proof is making a mistake which is tough to spot. With cardinalities the notation "$|A|=|B|$" is (usually) a shorthand for "there exists a bijection $A\to B$", thus the equality sign $=$ in this expression is technically not the logical operator, but a defined operator. Showing that the sets of $S$ are numerically equivalent means you have to show that $|A_i|=|A_j|$ for any $i,j$. It is true that $|A|=|B|$ and $|B|=|C|$ implies $|A|=|C|$ (and indeed the defined operator $=$ is an equivalence relation), but this is something you have to prove explicitly.

Comment: So, your last line $|A_1|=|A_2|=\cdots =|A_n|$ is not strictly speaking enough to state that all sets in $S$ are numerically equivalent.

Comment: @Vsotvep had the same reaction -- it's weird to do a proof about how you would do a proof!

Comment: @Vsotvep should I add after $|A_1|=|A_2|=\dots=|A_n|$ that because of the transitive property of equality we can conclude $|A_i|=|A_j|$ for all $i,j$? Or will I need to do more?

Comment: My point is that it is not the *transitive property of equality*, since the $=$ symbol does *not* technically stand for equality, which is a logical property. It stands for the existence of a bijection. The transitivity follows from the property that concatenating bijections with each other results in another bijection. Similarly, symmetry follows from bijections having a (bijective) inverse, and reflexivity follows from the identity map being a bijection. Hence the symbol $=$ is an equivalence relation between cardinalities.

Comment: @Vsotvep ah, so if I show a relation $R$ where $A_i\,R\,A_j$  if $|A_i|=|A_j|$ is an equivalence relation and then say that implies $|A_1|=\dots=|A_n|$ then the proof is complete?